# why does my game automatically close when I try to open Missions?

Tags: tiny-tower

When I try to open the Missions icon on the menu the game automatically closes?  What can I do to stop this?  Using an IPhone 4s IOS 8.1.3

Answer (score 1):

It's crashing - or put another way, failing to open successfully.

To fix it, try deleting the app including all app data and reinstalling it.

To delete the app, hold the home button until the apps are full of coffee (shaking) and then click the red x on the app. If it asks you to delete all the data, reply yes. Obviously this is a **destructive operation** and if you have any data, you'll lose it. But the chances of a reinstall fixing it without removing the data is unlikely.

If this still doesn't fix it (and especially if you've paid for the app) reach out to their support.